# Parse or split or explode mysql column by pattern

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with the following columns:

```
Id | Title | Status | Update_log
```

The data in the `Update_log` column looks like this:

> Priority Changed to Low. Transferred to user Operator. -- Thursday 30th July 2009 03:53:39 PM by Admin--//-- Status Changed to In Progress. -- Tuesday 15th September 2009 04:12:40 PM by Operator--//-- Status Changed to Closed. -- Friday 18th September 2009 10:39:22 AM by Admin--//--

I want to make a report like this:

```
Id | Title | Status | Status Changed In Progress Date | Status Changed In Closed Date | Time elapse from In Progress Date to Closed Date
```

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

When you get :

```
$update_log = $row["update_log"]; // "Coresponds to "Priority Changed to Low. Transferre ..."
```

Use :

```
$updates = explode("--//--",$update_log);
foreach($updates as $one_update) {
    $exploded_update = explode("--",$one_update);
    $log_txt = $exploded_update[0];  // ""
    $lod_date = $exploded_update[1];
}
```

So you can access each line of your log and for example store it in an array and do what you want.

Comment: It's ok till $updates = explode("--//--",$update_log). But then I need to select from the array the dates for two situations: "Status Status Changed to In Progress" and "Status Changed to Closed". This is what I'm confronted with and I don't know how.

Comment: So you need $updates[1] and $updates[2] (if your update log is exactly the same for each rows in your db)